# Mosquitto refuses WebSocket connection after update

Tags: websocket, mosquitto

after i´ve updated my mosquitto broker to 2.0.2, it refuses the ws connection from my webapp (8083).

tcp connection from java backend still works fine.

[image]

[image]

i´ve added

```
port 1883
listener 8083
protocol websockets
```

to my mosquitto.conf

Comment: What OS are you running this on? And which MQTT library are you using the in the webapp?

Comment: I'm currently on OSX 10.13 with ngx-mqtt.

Comment: Do you provide username/password when connecting from your webapp and from the java backend?

Comment: no, just a client id. backend still works. without anything changed but the websocket-connection can't established..

Answer (score 0):

With version 2.0.0 of mosquitto the broker is configured by default to deny any connection which does not provide a username:

> All listeners now default to `allow_anonymous false` unless explicitly set
> to true in the configuration file. This means that when configuring a
> listener the user must either configure an authentication and access control
> method, or set `allow_anonymous true`. When the broker is run without a
> configured listener, and so binds to the loopback interface, anonymous
> connections are allowed.

see [mosquitto changelog](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/blob/master/ChangeLog.txt)

Change your mosquitto.conf to `allow_anonymous true` to see if that's the problem in your case.

The connection from the backend might still work because you are connecting locally - although to my understanding of the changelog, this should only work if there is no listener configured at all. For sure this could also be a bug

Comment: your suggestion didn't work... I guess this is a bug. thx

Comment: Which return code do you get on your web app on connection attempt?

Comment: Operation couln´t be completed. Connection Reset by peer.